why does getClass method of Object class in java return the type of Object but reference type
When I studied static binding, private, final, static methods use static binding. (Static Vs. Dynamic Binding in Java)
So Static binding uses Type information for binding while dynamic binding uses object to resolve binding.
But why does getClass method returns object, it is final method though.
package BasePackage;

class A {

}
class B extends A {

}

public class project2{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        A a = new A();
        B b = new B();
        A c = new B();

        Class clazz1=c.getClass();
        System.out.println(clazz1.getName());
        System.out.println(clazz1.getSimpleName());
        System.out.println(clazz1.getPackageName());
        System.out.println(clazz1.getPackage());
        System.out.println(clazz1.getPackage().getName());
    }
}



What I expected as a result is A. Because getClass method is final method so static binding is used.
But the result is B.

c is an instance of B (new B()) so its class is B! Why would you expect A? It does not even declare getClass()

(final just means that the method can not be overridden by the subclasses of the class where it is declared final - bytecode generated to call a final method is the same as to call a non-final one)

First, Thank you for your answer. The reason I expected A is that I approached this problem with binding.

class A {
static char foo = 'a';
char foo2='c';
}
class B extends A {
static String foo = "b";
String foo2="d";
}
public class project2{
public static void main(String[] args){
A a = new A();
B b = new B();
A c = new B();
System.out.println(a.foo); // Prints 'a'
System.out.println(b.foo); // Prints "b"
System.out.println(c.foo); // Prints 'a'
System.out.println("-----------");
System.out.println(a.foo2); // Prints 'c'
System.out.println(b.foo2); // Prints "d"
System.out.println(c.foo2); // Prints "c"
}
}

Please look at this code. It doesn't matter static keyword exists or not the result always follows Type information of variable(instance). That's why I expected A would be an answer.

you asked about methods. Variables work differently

You're confusing variables of a type with the type of the actual object assigned to that variable.

‘Type information for variable (instance)’ is a contradiction in terms.

Thank you for your answers. Now I understand what I confused about. I organized the concept.

Binding merely determines which method to call. What that method does is a different matter.
There is only one getClass method, declared in Object. No matter what kind of binding is applied, there is only one choice here. It's not as if every class implicitly declares its own implementation of getClass to return its own class.
// This is NOT what happens. This does not compile.
// If this is indeed what happens under the hood, then it would work the way you expect
class A {
    public final Class<A> getClass() { return A.class; }
}
class B {
    public final Class<B> getClass() { return B.class; }
}

There is only one getClass method, declared in Object. You are always calling that method, and that method is implemented to return the class of the instance.
You might wonder how getClass could be implemented like this without dynamic binding. Well, getClass is implemented in native code, not Java, and that code can "look inside" the object instance, so to speak. See also: How does the getClass() is implemented in java?

Thank you for your answer. Now I can understand this concept. Thanks a lot!
